# Node.js & Express / Can context switch between two requests can be in synchronic code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in node.js, using `Express` module:

```
app.post('/saveDoc', function(req, res) {
    // Code to take params with req.busboy.on('field'...
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file) {
    var correctFlags = "";
    var exists = fs.existsSync(returnFilePath(uuid) + "/" + fileFor + "_part");
     if (exists){
         correctFlags = "r+"
     }
     else{
         correctFlags = "w"
      }
      var fstream1 = fs.createWriteStream(returnFilePath(uuid) + "/" + fileFor + "_part", {start: parseInt(start), flags: correctFlags});
      file.pipe(fstream1);
      })
```

The purpose of this code is to write to the same file some parts of it, in different offset (write files in chunks).

I want to ensure that only one chunk of the file will create the file, and write to it offset (using `"w"` flag), while the others will go to the `"r+"` flag.

I worried of the following scenario:

1. My server is getting 2 requests of `saveDoc` for `returnFilePath(uuid) + "/" + fileFor + "_part"`
2. Then the file is not still doesn't exists, and the two are getting the 'w' flag.

This can happens if there is a context switch between the request:

1. The first request will do the next command: var exists = `fs.existsSync(returnFilePath(uuid) + "/" + fileFor + "_part");` and get false.
2. context switch is done
3. The second will do the command: `var exists = fs.existsSync(returnFilePath(uuid) + "/" + fileFor + "_part");` and also get false.
4. The result is "false" for these two request.

Is this possible? Or in my code I ensure that all be done in synchronicity way, so context switch is impossible?

Comment: Do you mean "synchronous" code?

Comment: @NickTomlin: Yes, synchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong suspicion that this is not the correct format for what you want to do. A more structured solution, like storing your data in a database, or just something more structured like JSON, seems like a better.

That said, you can just use [`fs.appendFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback) since that will handle figuring whether to write or append.

Comment: I can use append file, but with file of 10GB and more, this can take a lot of time..